# What could cause duplicate records to be created by Rails?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails-3, nginx, duplicates, passenger

We are noticing a lot of duplicate records are being created in various tables in our database, but are at a loss as to why this is happening. Interestingly, while the records are otherwise duplicate (down to even the `created_at` stamps!), on our users table, the password salt and hash are different on each record -- which leads me to believe that somehow Rails is somehow running transactions/save operations twice. Obviously, we are not calling `save` or `create` multiple times in the application code.

This duplication does not seem to happen with every record saved in the database, and we cannot seem to infer a pattern yet. There is also a `validates_uniqueness_of` validation on the User model (though not a unique key on the table yet; we need to clean up all the duplicates to be able to do that) -- so Rails should stop itself if a record already exists, but if the requests are firing simultaneously that's a race condition.

We are currently running Rails 3.2.2 behind Passenger 3.0.11/nginx on our app servers (currently 2 of them), and have one central nginx webserver which sends requests upstream to an app server. Could this setup somehow cause processes to be duplicated or something? Would it matter that requests aren't locked to one upstream server (ie. if one user requests a page that includes static content like images, one or both app servers may be used)? (I feel like that's grasping at straws but I want to cover every possibility)

What else could cause this to happen?

***Update:*** As an example, a user was created today which got duplicate records. Both have the `created_at` stamp of `2012-03-28 16:48:11`, and all columns except for `hashed_password` and `salt` are identical. From the request log, I can see the following:

App Server 1:

```
Started POST "/en/apply/create_user" for 1.2.3.4 at 2012-03-28 12:47:19 -0400
[2012-03-28 12:47:19] INFO : Processing by ApplyController#create_user as HTML
[2012-03-28 12:47:20] INFO :   Rendered apply/new_user.html.erb within layouts/template (192.8ms)

Started POST "/en/apply/create_user" for 1.2.3.4 at 2012-03-28 12:48:10 -0400
[2012-03-28 12:48:10] INFO : Processing by ApplyController#create_user as HTML
[2012-03-28 12:48:11] INFO : Redirected to apply/initialize_job_application/3517
[2012-03-28 12:48:11] INFO :  /app/controllers/apply_controller.rb:263:in `block (2 levels) in create_user'
```

App Server 2:

```
Started POST "/en/apply/create_user" for 1.2.3.4 at 2012-03-28 12:48:10 -0400
[2012-03-28 12:48:10] INFO : Processing by ApplyController#create_user as HTML
```

Web Server:

```
1.2.3.4 - - [28/Mar/2012:12:48:10 -0400] "POST /en/apply/create_user HTTP/1.1" 499 0 "en/apply/create_user" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; Trident/5.0)" "-"
1.2.3.4 - - [28/Mar/2012:12:48:11 -0400] "POST /en/apply/create_user HTTP/1.1" 302 147 "en/apply/create_user" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; Trident/5.0)" "-"
```

So the create action was hit three times (returning to the form the first time due to an error, probably), and at least once on each server. The latter two both are registered by the webserver as separate requests, but the first gets status code `499 Client Closed Request` (an nginx extension according to wikipedia), and the second gets a `302` as expected. Could the 499 be causing the problems here?

Comment: Have you had a look through your application log files? When a duplicate user exists in the db can you find 2 requests in your log file corresponding to that point or just one?

Comment: We don't have full rails query logs in production, just the request log. The inserts are present in the mysql bin-log, however, and the create action is showing up in the request logs more than once for at least one example (though that wouldn't likely cause multiple *exact duplicate* records, no?)

Comment: But can you see pairs of requests that match te duplicate records or only single requests?

Comment: So either your nginx instance  that distributed requests to your app server is messing things up (unlikely I think) or there is a client side issue. Could it be a user double clicking? Were all your application server instances wedged for some reason? In that scenario an impatient user might hammer the create button, when the blockage clears all the requests would go through near simultaneously

Comment: It doesn't solve your problem, but shouldn't you at least enforce the uniqueness of the email address for instance at the database level?

Comment: maybe you have wrongly configured servers? could it happen that both servers process one request?

Comment: @Frederick: I forgot to mention that there is a `validates_uniqueness_of` validation on the model. I assume if the servers are responding normally, hammering the create button should not cause this situation - the first request will succeed and subsequent ones will hit the validation and fail. In general, does hammering a button queue up requests?

Comment: @Robin yes indeed but we can't do that until we clean up the duplicates that already exist in the table

Comment: Validates_uniquesness is vulnerable to race conditions: if two requests arrive simultaneously they will both check for an existing row, find none and then create a row. If you really care, add a unique index.

Comment: @Frederick: yeah, I know, but unfortunately the table needs to be cleaned up of duplicate records before mysql will allow a unique index (because the constraints will already be violated)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two possibilities come to mind.

The first one is an odd (and against the RFC) behavior of Nginx when used as a load balancer. It will retry any failed requests against the next backend. The RFC allows that only for safe methods (e.g. `GET` or `HEAD`). The result of this is that if your nginx considers a request failed for some reason, it might be that it is re-send to the next server. If both servers complete their transaction though, you have a duplicate record. Judging from your webservers log (and the 499 status code which Nginx uses to denote a user clicking abort in their browser) this looks like the most probable cause.

The second possibility is that your users double-click on the send button. With the right timing, their browsers could send two complete requests nearly at the same time.

To make sure that your user records are really unique, you should create unique indexes on your database. These are then actually ensured (albeit with a worse error message compared to the ActiveRecord check. Because of that, you should always define your uniqueness constraint on both the database schema and your models.

Also, you could look into replacing your frontend nginx with a more conformant loadbalancer. I'd recommend [haproxy](http://haproxy.1wt.eu) for that.

Comment: Is it plausible that the request can already make it upstream from the web server to the app server before the user aborts the request and the webserver nginx marks the request as `499`? In that case, would the request live on in the app server even though the web server knows it's terminated?

Comment: I think so. Once the request got dispatched to Rack, it doesn't abort anymore. So although your app-server-nginx might detect the connection abort, your rails stack doesn't know that and can't do anything about that. It completes its transaction while nginx discards the answer. All while your frontend loadbalancer has already erroneously redispatched the request.

Comment: That makes sense to me as well. Is there anything that can be done to prevent this (or do you think that putting haproxy into the mix is the solution)? Also, assuming only one app server existed, would this problem still be possible? In other words, if both requests were passed onto the same app server, would there still be a race condition, or would Passenger's queueing eliminate that?

Comment: I like my haproxy :) But you could at least configure [proxy_next_upstream](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpProxyModule#proxy_next_upstream) to not redispatch. I don't really know if it's any different on only one app server. That depends on how much passenger uses of the proxy code. But I'd guess you would be safe (without really knowing it for sure).

Comment: There's also https://github.com/xetorthio/nginx-upstream-idempotent /(mentioned from the previous linked to thread) which might be fixing the problem for POSTs, but still not all the other non-idempotent verbs (e.g. PUT, DELETE, ...)

Comment: If it's an issue of the user closing the connection and then opening a new one, that wouldn't be considered redispatching, would it? From what I see in my logs, I believe this is mostly (if not solely) caused by errant 499s that are still getting processed, but I suppose that we can try `proxy_next_upstream off` and see if that makes a difference, but since there are distinct requests with different status codes appearing in the log, my guess is that it won't.

Answer (score 0):

It really seems like a race condition. Make sure to lock between the requests. It could easily happen that one or two requests are duplicated every now and then. The same can happen when exchanging items without transactions, so please make sure that you don't have a race between your requests.

Comment: What would I be locking? I believe (correct me if I'm wrong) that Rails and/or mysql locks the tables that are in use in a transaction -- we have run into mysql lock errors before because a table was locked for too long.

Comment: Yes, but i am not talking about the transactions. I am talking about the requests that are sent to the servers. If your requests manager does not correctly assign the requests to the external servers, it could be very likely that you get a race condition, thus duplicating entries. It depends on how you have setup the manager, but it is a strong possibility i think.