# Rails + Nginx: HTTP 499 errors and clients repeating POSTs

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, nginx

So, I'm investigating MySQL deadlock exceptions on our Rails/Unicorn/Nginx app. What I've found is that sometimes, we'll see a storm of requests that get a 499 status code from one client. From [this post](http://forum.nginx.org/read.php?2,213789,213793#msg-213793), it looks like nginx returns 499 when the client closes the connection unexpectedly or, um, something. I'm not quite clear on whether the client actually sees the status code or not; I can't replicate this locally.

From the nginx logs, it looks like in these requests, we wind up writing 0 bytes to the client. In my Rails logs, there's nothing remarkable about the requests; they're finishing in normal amounts of time (40-120 ms) and returning a 302 redirect.

So, whatever, right? But! What makes this bad is that the client appears to be interpreting whatever it's seeing (or not seeing) as an invitation to try its request again. Even if it's a POST. And my Rails app is happily handling those requests and creating duplicate entries in the database. Sometimes it creates quite a lot of records — in one case, we had a client repeat a request some 6500 times over about ten minutes. That's... suboptimal.

I'm trying to figure out what to do. What I'd really like is to fix whatever interaction I'm seeing with nginx, but I'm not sure how — if the client is closing the connection before it gets data, I can't control what it's gonna do.

An alternative (which feels like a horrible hack) is to do something like include a unique key (say, from a [sequence](http://www.microshell.com/database/mysql/emulating-nextval-function-to-get-sequence-in-mysql/)) in a hidden form and have a unique index on the corresponding database column. But there are millions of rows on this table so screwing around with its schema is not something I want to do lightly.

In case it matters, the requests are being done via HTTPS. It looks like it comes most commonly from a small subset of our clients.

Has anyone else seen this (other than [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9914115/what-could-cause-duplicate-records-to-be-created-by-rails/9915140#9915140))? Am I totally mad? Can anyone think of an elegant solution?

Comment: I noticed this as well. NGINX + Unicorn, something is really strange. The client browser doesn't log multiple calls and the requests I have sometimes terminate with uncaught exceptions. If that happens inside a rescue block however the request is repeated. If I handle the exceptions however then the request does not repeat.

Maybe leaving uncaught exceptions (escaping past a rescue) is causing you some head_aches.

I was also using better_errors and a few other things in development that replay the errors explicitly.

Anything you find I'd love to know.

Comment: I see something similar. The timeout period is 1 minute in my web app. I make 5 JQuery Ajax requests in the UI to get some data. Randomly, some of these requests fail. When checked in nginx logs, it shows 499 error. When I refresh the page, some other set of these requests fail.

Comment: Any update on this, I'm getting this on JRuby and Trinidad... i sent some Jmeter tests at my box(es) and the rails gets the through but there are 40 (out of 400) 499 requests. no corresponding errors in the rails app either. Imma check that post out too. Let's figure this spit out!